# ActiveScaffold keeps rounding my numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal, activescaffold

I need to display & edit highly precise decimal numbers - latitude and longitude. ActiveScaffold keep rounding my values to precision 6 scale 3, can I change that to precision 11 scale 8 somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Are you specifying precision 11, scale 8 in the migration for the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used ActiveScaffold for quite a while but maybe this could do?

```
config.columns[:latitude].options[:format] = "%6.3f"
```

Comment: Thanks, will try to see if this works later. What do you use now? Any better option?

Comment: Not using anything like ActiveScaffold at the moment but I think I will check out http://hobocentral.net/blog/2010/02/23/hobo-1-0-released/ the next time I need something like that.

Comment: thanks, the doc for active scaffold is really unclear about that